# Using Html Agility Pack, Selecting the current element in a loop (XPATH)

Tags: c#, .net, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to do something simple, but somehow it doesnt work for me, here's my code:

```
var items = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='itembox']");
foreach(HtmlNode e in items)
{

     int x = items.count; // equals 10
     HtmlNode node = e;
     var test = e.SelectNodes("//a[@class='head']");// I need this to return the 
                                                // anchor of the current itembox 
                                                // but instead it returns the
                                                // anchor of each itembox element
     int y =test.count; //also equals 10!! suppose to be only 1
}
```

my html page looks like this:

```
....
<div class="itembox">
    <a Class="head" href="one.com">One</a>
</div>
<div class="itembox">
    <a Class="head" href="two.com">Two</a>
</div>
<!-- 10 itembox elements-->
....
```

Is my XPath expression wrong? am i missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
var test = e.SelectNodes(".//a[@class='head']");
```

instead. Your current code ( `//a[]`) searches all a elements starting from the root node. If you prefix it with a dot instead (`.//a[]`) only the descendants of the current node will be considered. Since it is a direct child in your case you could of course also do:

```
var test = e.SelectNodes("a[@class='head']");
```

As always see the [Xpath spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) for details.

Comment: wow, that dot was driving me crazy. thanks man, after 3 hours of working you got it for me in 1 min lol i should've asked earlier

Answer (score 0):

```
 var test = e.SelectNodes("//a[@class='head']");
```

This is an absolute expression, but you need a relative XPath expression -- to be evaluated off `e`.

**Therefore use**:

```
 var test = e.SelectNodes("a[@class='head']");
```

**Do note:** Avoid using the XPath `//` pseudo-operator as much as possible, because such use may result in significant inefficiencies (slowdown).

In this particular XML document the `a` elements are just children of `div` -- not at undefinite depth off `div`.